# Stopping wicket hyperlink refreshing page

Tags: java, javascript, html, wicket

Had to redo the snippet.I hope it's visible now. This is with the new code that when you select a block, they change backgroundcolor of td. Now I just nee to not change the color of the one that was clicked. Here we go again.

```css
    .active{background-color:red;}
```

```html
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
 xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 12 (filtered medium)">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="FNBStyle.css" type="text/css"
 media="screen" title="Stylesheet" />
<!--[if !mso]><style>v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
</style><![endif]-->
<title>Help Desk Survey</title>
<style>
<!-- /* Font Definitions */
@font-face {
 font-family: "Cambria Math";
 panose-1: 2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;
}

@font-face {
 font-family: Calibri;
 panose-1: 2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;
}

@font-face {
 font-family: Tahoma;
 panose-1: 2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;
}
/* Style Definitions */
p.MsoNormal,li.MsoNormal,div.MsoNormal {
 margin: 0cm;
 margin-bottom: .0001pt;
 font-size: 12.0pt;
 font-family: "Times New Roman", "serif";
}

a:link,span.MsoHyperlink {
 mso-style-priority: 99;
 text-decoration: none none;
}

td.TheSelection:hover
{
 
 background:#009999;
}





<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

```
a:visited,span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed {
    mso-style-priority: 99;
    text-decoration: none none;
}

td.TheSelection:active
{
    color:black;
}
td.red-cell {
    background: #F00; /* Or some other color */
}
a:hover {
    background: #009999;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
       -o-transition: all 1s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
          transition: all 1s ease;
}

p {
    mso-style-priority: 99;
    mso-margin-top-alt: auto;
    margin-right: 0cm;
    mso-margin-bottom-alt: auto;
    margin-left: 0cm;
    font-size: 12.0pt;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", "serif";
}

p.MsoAcetate,li.MsoAcetate,div.MsoAcetate {
    mso-style-priority: 99;
    mso-style-link: "Balloon Text Char";
    margin: 0cm;
    margin-bottom: .0001pt;
    font-size: 8.0pt;
    font-family: "Tahoma", "sans-serif";
}

span.BalloonTextChar {
    mso-style-name: "Balloon Text Char";
    mso-style-priority: 99;
    mso-style-link: "Balloon Text";
    font-family: "Tahoma", "sans-serif";
}

span.EmailStyle20 {
    mso-style-type: personal;
    color: black;
}

span.EmailStyle21 {
    mso-style-type: personal;
    font-family: "Calibri", "sans-serif";
    color: #009999;
}

span.EmailStyle22 {
    mso-style-type: personal;
    font-family: "Calibri", "sans-serif";
    color: #009999;
}

span.EmailStyle23 {
    mso-style-type: personal;
    color: white;
}

span.EmailStyle25 {
    mso-style-type: personal-reply;
    color: white;
}

.MsoChpDefault {
    mso-style-type: export-only;
    font-size: 10.0pt;
}

@page WordSection1 {
    size: 612.0pt 792.0pt;
    margin: 72.0pt 72.0pt 72.0pt 72.0pt;
}

div.WordSection1 {
    page: WordSection1;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<script>
function myHelpFunction() 
{
    var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    var i;

    for(i=1; i< 11; i++)
    {
        document.getElementById("help_cell" + i).style.backgroundColor = "lightgray";
    }
}

function myAgentFunction() 
{
    var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    var i;

    for(i=1; i< 11; i++)
    {
        document.getElementById("agent_cell" + i).style.backgroundColor = "lightgray";
    }
}



</script>

<!-- <script type="text/javascript">

$( function() {
      $('td').click( function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("red-cell");
      } );
    } );

</script> -->
<body lang=EN-ZA link=blue vlink=purple
    style='margin-top: 5.0pt; margin-bottom: 5.0pt'>

    <div id="HeaderContainer"> 
        <div id="Logo"></div>
    </div> 
<br><br><br><br>
    <form wicket:id="formSubmit">
    <div class=WordSection1>
        <p class=MsoNormal>
            <span style='color: white'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p> </span>
        </p>

        <div>
            <table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0
                width=700 style='width: 525.0pt'>

                <tr style='height: 15.0pt'>
                    <td colspan=3 style='padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm; height: 15.0pt'>
                        <p class=MsoNormal>
                            <span
                                style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif"; color: #222222'>
                                &nbsp;<o:p></o:p> </span>
                        </p></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width=20 style='width: 15.0pt; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm'>
                        <p class=MsoNormal>
                            <span
                                style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif"; color: #222222'>
                                &nbsp;<o:p></o:p> </span>
                        </p></td>
                    <td width=660 style='width: 495.0pt; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm'>


                        <p>


                            <span
                                style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif"; color: #222222'>
                                The Procurement Help Desk strives to deliver the highest level of service, and we would appreciate it if you could rate your most recent interaction with our agent, by selecting the appropriate score below. Your input is critical in helping us service you better. Although optional, it will assist us in understanding the service provided to you if you can provide us with comments and your details.<o:p></o:p> </span>
                        </p>
                        <p>


                            <span
                                style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif"; color: #222222'>
                                <span class="required">*</span>&nbsp;1. Please rate the service of the FNB Procurement Help Desk<o:p></o:p> </span>
                        </p>
                        <div align=center>


                            <table class=MsoNormalTable border=1 cellpadding=0 width=658
                                style='width: 493.5pt; background: #F9F9F9; border: solid #009999 1.0pt'>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style='border: none; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm'>
                                        <div align=center>
                                            <table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellpadding=0
                                                width="85%" style='width: 85.0%'>
                                                <tr style='height: 114.0pt'>
                                                    <td width="40%"
                                                        style='width: 40.0%; padding: .75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt; height: 114.0pt'><p
                                                            class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align: center'>
                                                            <strong><span
                                                                style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif"; color: #222222'>Not
                                                                    Likely</span> </strong><span
                                                                style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif"; color: #222222'><br>(Not
                                                                good enough) <o:p></o:p> </span>
                                                        </p>
                                                        <div align=center>
                                                            <table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0
                                                                cellpadding=0 width="80%" style='width: 80.0%'>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td width="50%"
                                                                        style='width: 50.0%; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm'><p
                                                                            class=MsoNormal align=center
                                                                            style='text-align: center'>
                                                                            <span
                                                                                style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif"; color: #222222'>&nbsp;<o:p></o:p>
                                                                            </span>
                                                                        </p>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td
                                                                        style='border: none; border-left: dotted #333333 1.0pt; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm'><p
                                                                            class=MsoNormal align=center
                                                                            style='text-align: center'>
                                                                            <span
                                                                                style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif"; color: #222222'>&nbsp;<o:p></o:p>
                                                                            </span>
                                                                        </p>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td colspan=2
                                                                        style='border: dotted #333333 1.0pt; border-bottom: none; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm'><p
                                                                            class=MsoNormal align=center
                                                                            style='text-align: center'>
                                                                            <span
                                                                                style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif"; color: #222222'>&nbsp;<o:p></o:p>
                                                                            </span>
                                                                        </p>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align: center'>
                                                            <span
                                                                style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif"; color: #222222; display: none'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p>
                                                            </span>
                                                        </p>
                                                        <div align=center>
                                                            <table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=5 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width: 100.0%'>
                                                                <tr style='height: 30.0pt'>
                                                                    <td width=30 
                                                                    style='width: 22.5pt;  background: #FF0004; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm; height: 30.0pt'
                                                                    id=help_cell1>
                                                                    <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align: center'>
                                                                            <span style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif"; color: #222222'>
                                                                            <a href="#" onclick="myHelpFunction()" wicket:id="help_one"><b>
                                                                            <span style='display:block; font-size: 12.0pt; color: white'>1</span> </b>
                                                                            </a> <o:p></o:p> 
                                                                            </span>
                                                                        </p>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td width=30
                                                                        style='width: 22.5pt; background: #FF0004; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm; height: 30.0pt'
                                                                        id=help_cell2><p class=MsoNormal align=center
                                                                            style='text-align: center'>
                                                                            <span
                                                                                style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif"; color: #222222'><a
                                                                                href="#" onclick="myHelpFunction()" wicket:id="help_two"><b><span
                                                                                        style='display:block; font-size: 12.0pt; color: white'>2</span> </b>
                                                                            </a> <o:p></o:p> </span>
                                                                        </p>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td width=30
                                                                        style='width: 22.5pt; background: #FF0004; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm; height: 30.0pt'
                                                                        id=help_cell3><p class=MsoNormal align=center
                                                                            style='text-align: center'>
                                                                            <span
                                                                                style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif"; color: #222222'><a
                                                                                href="#" onclick="myHelpFunction()" wicket:id="help_three"><b><span
                                                                                        style='display:block; font-size: 12.0pt; color: white'>3</span> </b>
                                                                            </a> <o:p></o:p> </span>
                                                                        </p>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td width=30
                                                                        style='width: 22.5pt; background: #FF0004; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm; height: 30.0pt'
                                                                        id=help_cell4><p class=MsoNormal align=center
                                                                            style='text-align: center'>
                                                                            <span
                                                                                style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif"; color: #222222'><a
                                                                                href="#" onclick="myHelpFunction()" wicket:id="help_four"><b><span
                                                                                        style='display:block; font-size: 12.0pt; color: white'>4</span> </b>
                                                                            </a> <o:p></o:p> </span>
                                                                        </p>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td width=30
                                                                        style='width: 22.5pt; background: #FF0004; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm; height: 30.0pt'
                                                                        id=help_cell5><p class=MsoNormal align=center
                                                                            style='text-align: center'>
                                                                            <span
                                                                                style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif"; color: #222222'><a
                                                                                href="#" onclick="myHelpFunction()" wicket:id="help_five"><b><span
                                                                                        style='display:block; font-size: 12.0pt; color: white'>5</span> </b>
                                                                            </a> <o:p></o:p> </span>
                                                                        </p>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td width=30
                                                                        style='width: 22.5pt; background: #FF0004; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm; height: 30.0pt'
                                                                        id=help_cell6><p class=MsoNormal align=center
                                                                            style='text-align: center'>
                                                                            <span
                                                                                style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif"; color: #222222'><a
                                                                                href="#" onclick="myHelpFunction()" wicket:id="help_six"><b><span
                                                                                        style='display:block; font-size: 12.0pt; color: white'>6</span> </b>
                                                                            </a> <o:p></o:p> </span>
                                                                        </p>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align: center'>
                                                            <o:p></o:p>
                                                        </p>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td width="14%"
                                                        style='width: 14.0%; padding: .75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt; height: 114.0pt'><p
                                                            class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align: center'>
                                                            <strong><span
                                                                style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif"; color: #222222'>Likely</span>
                                                            </strong><b><span
                                                                style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif"; color: #222222'><br>
                                                            </span> </b><span
                                                                style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif"; color: #222222'>(We
                                                                can do better) <o:p></o:p> </span>
                                                        </p>
                                                        <div align=center>
                                                            <table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0
                                                                cellpadding=0 width="50%" style='width: 50.0%'>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td width="50%"
                                                                        style='width: 50.0%; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm'><p
                                                                            class=MsoNormal align=center
                                                                            style='text-align: center'>
                                                                            <span
                                                                                style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif"; color: #222222'>&nbsp;<o:p></o:p>
                                                                            </span>
                                                                        </p>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td
                                                                        style='border: none; border-left: dotted #333333 1.0pt; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm'><p
                                                                            class=MsoNormal align=center
                                                                            style='text-align: center'>
                                                                            <span
                                                                                style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif"; color: #222222'>&nbsp;<o:p></o:p>
                                                                            </span>
                                                                        </p>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td colspan=2
                                                                        style='border: dotted #333333 1.0pt; border-bottom: none; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm'><p
                                                                            class=MsoNormal align=center
                                                                            style='text-align: center'>
                                                                            <span
                                                                                style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif"; color: #222222'>&nbsp;<o:p></o:p>
                                                                            </span>
                                                                        </p>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align: center'>
                                                            <span
                                                                style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif"; color: #222222; display: none'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p>
                                                            </span>
                                                        </p>
                                                        <div align=center>
                                                            <table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=5
                                                                cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width: 100.0%'>
                                                                <tr style='height: 30.0pt'>
                                                                    <td width=30
                                                                        style='width: 22.5pt; background: #FF7F00; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm; height: 30.0pt'
                                                                        id=help_cell7><p class=MsoNormal align=center
                                                                            style='text-align: center'>
                                                                            <span
                                                                                style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif"; color: #222222'><a
                                                                                href="#" onclick="myHelpFunction()" wicket:id="help_seven"><b><span
                                                                                        style='display:block; font-size: 12.0pt; color: white'>7</span> </b>
                                                                            </a> <o:p></o:p> </span>
                                                                        </p>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td width=30
                                                                        style='width: 22.5pt; background: #FF7F00; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm; height: 30.0pt'
                                                                        id=help_cell8><p class=MsoNormal align=center
                                                                            style='text-align: center'>
                                                                            <span
                                                                                style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif"; color: #222222'><a
                                                                                href="#" onclick="myHelpFunction()" wicket:id="help_eight"><b><span
                                                                                        style='display:block; font-size: 12.0pt; color: white'>8</span> </b>
                                                                            </a> <o:p></o:p> </span>
                                                                        </p>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align: center'>
                                                            <o:p></o:p>
                                                        </p>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td width="13%"
                                                        style='width: 13.0%; padding: .75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt; height: 114.0pt'><p
                                                            class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align: center'>
                                                            <strong><span
                                                                style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif"; color: #222222'>Absolutely</span>
                                                            </strong><span
                                                                style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif"; color: #222222'><br>(We
                                                                did great) <o:p></o:p> </span>
                                                        </p>
                                                        <div align=center>
                                                            <table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0
                                                                cellpadding=0 width="50%" style='width: 50.0%'>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td width="50%"
                                                                        style='width: 50.0%; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm'><p
                                                                            class=MsoNormal align=center
                                                                            style='text-align: center'>
                                                                            <span
                                                                                style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif"; color: #222222'>&nbsp;<o:p></o:p>
                                                                            </span>
                                                                        </p>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td
                                                                        style='border: none; border-left: dotted #333333 1.0pt; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm'><p
                                                                            class=MsoNormal align=center
                                                                            style='text-align: center'>
                                                                            <span
                                                                                style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif"; color: #222222'>&nbsp;<o:p></o:p>
                                                                            </span>
                                                                        </p>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td colspan=2
                                                                        style='border: dotted #333333 1.0pt; border-bottom: none; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm'><p
                                                                            class=MsoNormal align=center
                                                                            style='text-align: center'>
                                                                            <span
                                                                                style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif"; color: #222222'>&nbsp;<o:p></o:p>
                                                                            </span>
                                                                        </p>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align: center'>
                                                            <span
                                                                style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif"; color: #222222; display: none'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p>
                                                            </span>
                                                        </p>
                                                        <div align=center>
                                                            <table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=5
                                                                cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width: 100.0%'>
                                                                <tr style='height: 30.0pt'>
                                                                    <td width=30
                                                                        style='width: 22.5pt; background: #709F32; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm; height: 30.0pt'
                                                                        id=help_cell9><p class=MsoNormal align=center
                                                                            style='text-align: center'>
                                                                            <span
                                                                                style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif"; color: #222222'><a
                                                                                href="#" onclick="myHelpFunction()" wicket:id="help_nine"><b><span
                                                                                        style='display:block; font-size: 12.0pt; color: white'>9</span> </b>
                                                                            </a> <o:p></o:p> </span>
                                                                        </p>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td width=30
                                                                        style='width: 22.5pt; background: #709F32; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm; height: 30.0pt'
                                                                        id=help_cell10><p class=MsoNormal align=center
                                                                            style='text-align: center'>
                                                                            <span
                                                                                style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif"; color: #222222'><a
                                                                                href="#" onclick="myHelpFunction()" wicket:id="help_ten"><b><span
                                                                                        style='display:block; font-size: 12.0pt; color: white'>10</span>
                                                                                </b> </a> <o:p></o:p> </span>
                                                                        </p>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>

                                                            </table>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align: center'>
                                                            <o:p></o:p>
                                                        </p>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>

                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </td>

                    <td width=20 style='width: 15.0pt; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm'><p
                            class=MsoNormal>
                            <span
                                style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif"; color: #222222'>&nbsp;<o:p></o:p>
                            </span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><p></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
            <p>
                            <span
                                style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif"; color: #222222'>
                                <span class="required">*</span>&nbsp;2. Please select an agent that assisted you and rate their service.<o:p></o:p> </span>
                        </p></td></tr>
            <tr>
            <td style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif";'></td>
            <td><select wicket:id="fromConsultants"></select></td>
        </tr>

                <tr style='height: 15.0pt'>
                    <td colspan=3 style='padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm; height: 15.0pt'>
                        <p class=MsoNormal>
                            <span
                                style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif"; color: #222222'>
                                &nbsp;<o:p></o:p> </span>
                        </p></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width=20 style='width: 15.0pt; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm'>
                        <p class=MsoNormal>
                            <span
                                style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif"; color: #222222'>
                                &nbsp;<o:p></o:p> </span>
                        </p></td>
                    <td width=660 style='width: 495.0pt; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm'>



                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
        </div>
        <p class=MsoNormal>
            <o:p>&nbsp;</o:p>
        </p>
    </div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif";'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Please Enter your details here (Optional)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif";'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Employee Number:</td>
            <td><input type="text" wicket:id="empNumber" size="42" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif";'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Employee Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" wicket:id="empName" size="42" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif";'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Business Unit:</td>
            <td><input type="text" wicket:id="BU" size="42" /></td>
        </tr>

    </table >
    <table >
            <tr>
                <td style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif";'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Comment:</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<textarea cols=90 rows=4 wicket:id="comment"></textarea></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><div wicket:id="feedbackPanel"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you include a fidler or code snipet?

Comment: due to characters in the snippet, I had to remove the second table, which is exactly the same table as the above one. And that is the second table that has the link I don't want to refresh. @xzegga

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it.

```
function myHelpFunction() 
{
    var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    var i;

    for(i=1; i< 11; i++)
    {
        document.getElementById("help_cell" + i).style.backgroundColor = "lightgray";
    }
}
```

Here is the latest one that works for the colors. Now what is left is to make all this work in Wicket.

```
function myHelpFunction(link) 
{
    var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    var i;

    for(i=1; i< 12; i++)
    {
        if(link >= 1 && link <=6)
        {
            document.getElementById("help_cell" + link).style.backgroundColor = "#FF0004";
        }
        if(link == 7 || link ==8)
        {
            document.getElementById("help_cell" + link).style.backgroundColor = "#FF7F00";
        }
        if(link == 9 || link ==10)
        {
            document.getElementById("help_cell" + link).style.backgroundColor = "#709F32";
        }

        document.getElementById("help_cell" + i).style.backgroundColor = "lightgray";
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I need to not change the color of the one that was not clicked. Java is fun for a beginner like me

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Wicket AjaxLink component. Or don't use a Wicket component at all.

Normal (i.e. non-Ajax) Link will "refresh" the page because it sends a request that executes Link's #onClick() method and the whole page is refreshed to show the outcome of the click.
You can use JavaScript to suppress the default behavior of `<a>` but then do you really need a Link in your page?! You can use plain JavaScript to change colors on the client side. Use `#renderHead(IHeaderResponse)` to contribute your.js file that binds event listeners and does the work.

Comment: I need the links. But I'll keep on searching for an answer. There goes 2 more votes.

Comment: You will have to provide more information about the use case if you want to get more help. The provided CSS and HTML code doesn't help to understand your case.

Comment: I am going to redo the whole thing because I tried it using Notepad++ and it works but as soon as I take the html code into wicket and try out the functionality in the java class, it wobbles. Maybe it's just me being too much of a beginner.